# Entity Framework 6 Batch Updates and AuditLog using Entity Framework Extended

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-extended

I am using Entity Framework 6 and I am using  EntityFramework Extended to perform some batch updates and batch deletes. The batch updates and batch deletes work OK however I also need to know the entities that were updated / deleted (i.e. the current and previous values). I thought  that using the AuditLogger provided by EntityFramework.Extended would provide me with the details of the entities that where updated or deleted however this does not seem to be the case. For example, using the code below i.e.

```
var auditor =dbContext.BeginAudit();
dbContext.Addresses.Update(ent => new Address { AddressId = 1190 });
dbContext.SaveChanges();
var changes = auditor.LastLog;
```

This is simple batch update to update all addressIds to `1190`.
If I inspect `changes.Entities`, it returns a Count of 0 i.e. an empty list.

What I was expecting was that `changes.Entities` would contain all the 'old' entities with the old values before the addressId was changed to `1190`.

Am I mistaken or is this indeed the correct behaviour? How can I get an audit log of all updated entities when using Entity framework Extended batch update / delete

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable the Auditor

```
var auditConfiguration = AuditConfiguration.Default;
auditConfiguration.IncludeRelationships = true;
auditConfiguration.LoadRelationships = true;
auditConfiguration.DefaultAuditable = true;
```

just add it to place where your app is initialized, Global.asax.cs for example

**edited**

Far as I know you can't get old values using EF.Extended.
Here is my solution:

override SaveChanges method in the Context

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        return SaveChanges(false);
    }

    public int SaveChanges(bool disableAudit)
    {
        var result = -1;
        try
        {
            if (!disableAudit)
            {
                foreach (var entity in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added ||
                                                                          x.State == EntityState.Modified ||
                                                                          x.State == EntityState.Deleted))
                {
                    ProccessAuditLog(entity);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle the ex here
        }
        finally
        {
            //save changes
            result = base.SaveChanges();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

and add method to process audit logging:

```
private void ProccessAuditLog(DbEntityEntry entry)
    {
        var entity = entry.Entity;
        var entityType = GetEntityType(entity.GetType());

        var oldValue = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType); ;
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            // entry.OriginalValues doesn't load navigation properties for changed entity so we should reload the object from db to get it
            // save current values
            var newValue = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);
            Mapper.DynamicMap(entity, newValue, entity.GetType(), entityType);

            // reload old values for entity from the db
            entry.Reload();
            Mapper.DynamicMap(entry.Entity, oldValue, entity.GetType(), entityType);

            // revert reloading changes in entity
            entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(newValue);
            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(oldValue);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            entity = newValue;
        }

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            // reload old values for entity from the db
            entry.Reload();
            Mapper.DynamicMap(entry.Entity, oldValue, entity.GetType(), entityType);

            // revert reloading changes in entity
            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(oldValue);
            entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            entity = null;
        }

        // here is you can proccess old entity in 'oldValue' and new entity in 'entity'
        // then save your log to db using SaveChanges(true) to prevent StackOverFlow exception
    }
```

As `Mapper` you can use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

method to get base entity's type instead proxy type:

```
private Type GetEntityType(Type entityType)
        {
            return entityType.BaseType != null && entityType.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies"
                    ? entityType.BaseType
                    : entityType;
        }
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Hi @Temaska, I have enabled the auditor but I am still getting the same results

Comment: Hi @Temaska. I eventually had to go with something similar to what you have provided although in my case I had to use a stored proc on the db to effect the auditing. In any case, your solution is also correct so I will mark that as the correct answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Temaska what is the namespace for `AuditConfiguration`?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed it comes from EntityFramework.Extended: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/